# adding strip to single dotplot from lattice package

Tags: r, lattice, strip

I have a situation where I have two different kind of plots and I need to plot them together along with strips on their top stating their heading. I have to use lattice package only thus ggplot2 is not an option. Thanks

I have a sample code here :

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
X<-rnorm(100)
Y<-rnorm(100)
S<- rnorm(500)
df1<-data.frame(X,Y,S)

p1<-dotplot(X~Y, data=df1)

p2<-dotplot(X~S, data=df1)

#combining plots
c(p1,p2)
```

Comment: One way would be to rearrange your data and use the standard `|` notation in your formula to create different panels. Something like `dotplot(X ~ value | variable, data = reshape2::melt(df1, id.vars = "X"))`.

Comment: Thanks,for great suggestion but my rearrangement won't be really helpful as i have two different type of groups for both of these plots

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to stack the variables `Y` and `S` and create an additional column indicating what variable each value comes from.

```
> df2 <- reshape(df1, varying=2:3, v.names='Value', timevar='Var', times=c('Y','S'), direction='long')
> head(df2)
             X Var      Value id
1.Y -2.3720450   Y  2.3965643  1
2.Y  0.8082862   Y  0.0215850  2
3.Y  0.3774736   Y -0.6385176  3
4.Y  0.7161986   Y -0.3908185  4
5.Y -0.3633583   Y -0.9611222  5
6.Y -0.3484920   Y  3.3387813  6
```

Then

```
> dotplot(X ~ Value | Var, data = df2)
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
p1 <- dotplot(X~Y, data=df1)
p2 <- dotplot(X~S, data=df1)
c(
    "Here is plot 1" = p1
    ,"And here second one" = p2
)
```

or:

```
p1 <- dotplot(X~Y|"Here is plot 1", data=df1)
p2 <- dotplot(X~S|"And here second one", data=df1)
c(p1, p2)
```

First one seems better cause you create the strip where you need it.